# Mysql - Archiving database and maintining references

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds grocery information such as:

```
id
typeid
groceryname
grocerydesc
```

Each night I copy that table into a new table to archive it. The typeid field references to a second table that holds the grocery type options:

```
id
typename
```

Then in the grocery table I reference the id for the type selected. My question is once its archived what happens if the typename is updated in the grocery type table? For example lets say there is an entry for soda in the grocery type table, then its archived. Now the person changed Soda to Water, now all the entries in archive reference to water which is incorrect. What is the best way to handle this? Do I instead grab the type name and archive that along with the grocery entry instead of the type id? But then Im querying the archive table via text rather than a numeric value, wouldnt that be slower? Or do I just tell them if you change it, it will update the listings in the archive table as well?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set the `ON UPDATE` clausole in your tables and what kind of engine have your tables. If you set the ON UPDATE CASCADE and your tables are innodb, for example, if you update the value in the main table then the value is update in the referenced table too.

You can read more on this type of behavior here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Well the id stays the same, the only thing they can update is the name of that type. But the id will always stay the same so the reference is always correct, its just the name itself could be changed so it could have a different meaning.

Comment: If the id will remains the same and you just want to update also the archive, you can do a little query in your favorite server-side language and update them.